# Calculating interesting volume (Also general multiple variable function equation)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

First off, What does $f(x,y,z) = 1$ mean? versus  $f(x,y,z) = x$.

I have trouble with this as I am not sure choosing an initial $x$ factors into the function. Similarly with choosing a corresponding z. (The choices are related to the problem).

OK, so, I am trying to find the volume of the following shape. For a given x, $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $0 \leq z \leq x$. For a given z based on the initial choice of x, $0 \leq y \leq\sqrt{1-z^2}$.

So, is the volume $$\int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_0^\sqrt{1-z^2} x dydzdx?$$

Or is it $$\int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_0^\sqrt{1-z^2} 1 dydzdx?$$

I also worry about the arbitrary choice of $z$ after the original choice of $x$. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, well, sorry to bother, but can you tell me the volume? I'll think about your response further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINTS**

$f(x,y,z)=1$ means $f$ maps any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $1$. When you say $g(x,y,z)=x$, this means that $g$ maps any vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to its first coordinate.

Volume of the region $A$ is *defined* as $\iiint_A dV$.